# Does DFR0063 I2C LCD work with Arduino Due? I cannot even pass i2C scanner

Tags: i2c, arduino-due

I have 2 Due and Two DFR0063 I2C LCD.  I cannot even pass i2C scanner.
I always got No I2C devices found.  I tried both SCL/SDA and SCL1/SDA1. For SCL1/SDA1, I do add 10K pull up resister. But still not work.
I notice most of example is using Arduino Uno not Due.  So I wonder maybe they just not work together.
I actually just need any Chelp I2C device work smoothy with DUE not other board.
Anyone recommend any goof I2C device for DUE?

Thanks

Joseph

Comment: See this [link](https://forums.adafruit.com/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=73118&p=418612#p418323) about i2c problem on Due, this was several years ago so not sure whether this was fixed or not.